# how to properly encode contentUrl in MPMoviePlayerController to allow for spaces?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using the MPMoviePlayerController to play video in an iPad app.  When I set contentUrl to a local file with a space in the name, the player won't acknowledge or play the file, not even an error.  IF I urlEncode the path, it fails with an error ("can't play file").

Does anyone know how to properly encode contentUrl in MPMoviePlayerController to allow for spaces?

Answer (score 0):

How are you constructing the URL? If you use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPath]` that should give you an `NSURL*` that's correct.